# need help understanding why css cursor:pointer; works on some elements and not others

Tags: html, css, cursor-position

i'm working on a mini [project](https://cosmo-drama.github.io/google-search_results-page/) (also not mobile friendly yet) where i'm re-building google's search result's page just to get some practice in. i'm putting the finishing touches on everything and for some reason, most of the places i've put 'cursor: pointer; no longer work. specifically, the search bar and its components, as well as the square menu button and sign in button. it works on the top nav, and on all the links on the page.

i tried adding some css resets, with no luck. also tried adding cursor: inherit to different elements, but no dice.

here's some snippets of the html:

```
            <div class="logo">
                <img class="google-logo" src="images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <form class="search-form">
                    <div class="searching">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input class="search-bar" type="text" name="search">
                    <img title="Search by Voice" class="search-mic" src="images/svb2.png"/>
                    <div class="clear">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
<div class="move-right">
                <li>
                    <svg class="square-menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
width="24" height="24"
viewBox="0 0 172 172"
style=" fill:#000000;"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,172v-172h172v172z" fill="none"></path><g fill="#cccccc"><path d="M21.5,21.5v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667zM71.66667,21.5v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667zM121.83333,21.5v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667zM21.5,71.66667v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667zM71.66667,71.66667v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667zM121.83333,71.66667v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667zM21.5,121.83333v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667zM71.66667,121.83333v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667zM121.83333,121.83333v28.66667h28.66667v-28.66667z"></path></g></g></svg>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="sign-in-btn">Sign In</button>
                </li>
                </div>
        </div>
```

and css:

```
.top-container {
    height: 50px;
}

.search {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;

}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;  
}

.search {
    top: 10px;
    left: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.search-form{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

 .search-mic, .clear {
    position: absolute;


}

.search-bar {
    width: 99vh;
    height: 45px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: inherit;

}

.search-bar:hover{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #5f6368;
}

.searching {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: -180px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #4285F4;

}


.search-mic {
    top: 12px;
    width: 36px;
    right: -130px;
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.clear{
    top: 12px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 1px;
    right: -65px;
    color: grey;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.move-right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 0px;
}
#top {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I inspect your code and the problem is not on the cursors, rather an overlap of elements. Try inspecting "sign in" button for instance and you'll see that an `<ul>` element gets highlighted instead. It's happening because: 

 - there's an overuse of `position: relative`. When you say `top: -60px`, for instance, the element will go up but won't push the previous element up as well. 

 - you should not use `transform: scale()` to redefine an element size, since it does not affect its real dimensions.  Rely on `width` or `height` instead.

Comment: @MarceloF. thank you, i see exactly what you're talking about. i had no idea that was bad form. and i had a feeling i was overusing position but im not really sure what else to use to position my css. the ul that is overlapping the sign in button is supposed to be for the top navigation bar under the  search bar. its overlapping the search bar too. what can i use to more effectively position elements?

Comment: Think of elements as blocks. Your `.top-container` should occupy space according to its content, hence `#top`, being the subsequent block, should naturally come directly below it, with no need for `position` declarations.  It's not happening in your code because `.top-container` has zero height, caused by children  with `absolute` position, which makes elements behave in a way their dimensions do not affect the other elements. Try removing the absolute and the scale() of the logo and you'll note something (:

Comment: @MarceloF. ah that makes so much sense! i was wondering why i couldn't even see the space the .top-container took up. i made the adjustments u suggested and my cursor:pointers; are all working, but the ul is still huge. it's like it has a margin-top, but when i try to change the margins, nothing changes. (i edited the code above to reflect the changes, and the link is updated as well)

Comment: Just realized there was another element that I had 'resized' using 'transform'. that fixed everything. thanks again @MarceloF.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep up with your learning! (-;